# For below program, when threads finish their work, why doesn't main thread stops?

Tags: java, multithreading

This program works fine by printing alternate numbers via different threads but when all the numbers from 0-9 are printed Why does this program not stop? I have to manually stop my application.

```
public class EvenOddPrinter  implements Runnable{

private AtomicInteger num = new AtomicInteger(0);
private Object lock = new Object();

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (lock){
        while (num.get()<10){
            System.out.println(num.getAndAdd(1) + " - "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            lock.notify();
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}

public class Executor {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        EvenOddPrinter eop = new EvenOddPrinter();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(eop);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(eop);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's stuck at `wait()` obviously. But the lock is pointless altogether if you're using an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Ah! correct. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because in the last Thread getting stuck at `wait`. `notifyAll` will notify all waiting thread if any there and release lock.

```
while (num.get()<10){
  // existing implementation
}
lock.notifyAll();
```

Comment: Oh well, I figured that out as well. As soon as I posted my answer the page refreshed to show your answer. Thanks a lot for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

The second thread t2 keeps waiting on the lock in the end, and t1 doesnt do the notify() anymore because the while condition becomes false. You must put a lock.notify(); statement outside of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the number reached 8 the first thread calls notify() and goes to wait(). Second thread then makes the number 9 and calls notify() and goes to wait(). First thread is then not able to go inside the loop as specified in the condition, therefore, it exits the synchronized and block and finishes but second thread is still waiting. There has to be a mechanism to notifyAll() as soon as one of the threads exits the synchronized block which is exactly what I did.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (lock){
        while (num.get()<10){
            System.out.println(num.getAndAdd(1) + " - "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            lock.notify();
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
```

Also, lock is pointless when I am using AtomicInteger (or the other way round).